# How can I filter a rendered column on a grid in Ext.js 4.2.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, xpages

I have a column on my grid that is rendered based on the selected language. When I filter this column I can only find results based on the original language. How can I make the filtering work for people with a different language?

My code for the column looks like this now:
(for example: labels.statusDraft is the dynamic name for draft in the selected language)

```
{
  text: labels.Status,
  width: 100,
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'btStatus',
  filterable: true,
  field: {xtype: 'textfield'},              
  renderer: function(value){
            switch(value){
            case 'draft':
              status=labels.statusDraft;
              break;
            case 'approvalRequested':
              status=labels.statusApprovalRequested;
              break;
            case 'approved':
              status=labels.statusApproved;
              break;
            case 'rejected':
              status=labels.statusRejected;
              break;
            case 'archived':
              status=labels.statusArchived;
              break;
            default:
              status= value;
            };
            return status;
            }               
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter in the column can only filter the information which is fed to it in the data.

If you are storing a single value in the notes document and displayed the translation value to a customer on the XPage you just need to do a similar thing to your data source.

Assuming you are using an ExtLib REST service to provide the data (or if you are doing it yourself it is still applicable) what you need to do it create a hand made column in the REST service and do the translation before the data is sent out.

In a case like this you need to store an aliased version of the "Status" in the database and not just the original language value. That will then allow you to do a translation on the fly like this.